# finding rows with specific values for a column (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I Have a matrix in matlab,for example

```
A=[1 2 3
   1 3 5
   1 4 2
   2 3 1
   2 4 3]
```

and an array like this:

```
b=[3
   4]
```

now I want to find rows in A, that the second column equals one of the values in b. In this example:

```
Result=[1 3 5
        1 4 2
        2 3 1
        2 4 3]
```

I want to find this without using loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need loop for this. Else you cant compare all the values in the array

Comment: @LifeofMadness In Matlab you can often avoid loops by using certain functions. Of course, those functions probably have a loop internally, but you don't explicity write the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy: use the [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
Result = A(ismember(A(:,2),b),:);
```

You could also use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Result = A(any(bsxfun(@eq, A(:,2).', b(:)),1),:)
```

Comment: Thanks,
how to do this when the second array is a matrix and  when I want to find rows??

Comment: @Ana.IM If the second array is a matrix, what is the matching condition? If this is a substantial change to the original question, better ask a new question. Please include an example with inputs and desired output